Is it possible to use federated queries from GCP Dataform?
I'd like to query tables in CloudSQL from Dataform.
I set up an external connection to the CloudSQL database in bigquery, and am able to get query results when I run the federated query from BigQuery.
However, when I try to run the same query from a GCP Dataform job, it does not work, and I get an error that it cannot find the connection.
Is it possble to run federated queries from GCP Datafrom, and if so which setting and/or permissions are needed to get this working?
In BigQuery, i have setup a external connection named external-connection-test
In Dataform I have:
federated.sqlx:
config {
type: "table",
} 

SELECT
*
FROM
  EXTERNAL_QUERY("projects/my-project/locations/my-location/connections/external-connection-test",
"SELECT * from example_table'")

When I run the query in BigQuery it returns the expected results, but when I run it in BigQuery it get this warning:


Dataform run SQL, so the answer is YES. However, I don't know how it does not work for you. Do you have config file or screen shot to share?

Yes I'd say at in theory this should be possible as Dataform just runs SQL queries on BigQuery, but it does not seem to work.

Are you running Dataform in the same project as the connection definition? if not, the Dataform runtime service account must be  roles/bigquery.connectionUser on the project where the connection is defined

Yes this in the same project, and the dataform service acount has roles/bigquery.connectionUser

Hi @ChrisBlom, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
